# SwiftUI: Navigation Bar Title in Reusable Cross-Platform (iOS & macOS) View

Tags: swift, macos, frameworks, swiftui, navigationbar

I'm attempting to create reusable SwiftUI `View` for a framework, which can then be used across both iOS/iPadOS and macOS.

This generally works fine; however, because macOS views don't have navigation bars, including a navigation bar title (important for iOS) causes an error when the view's included in a macOS target:

`.navigationBarTitle(Text("Page Title"))`

> Value of type '...' has no member 'navigationBarTitle'

Any suggestions on a conditional compilation (or any other) approach that can allow the same view to build for both platforms?

The closest I've come is the following. Including the extra `Text` view is easy enough, but because the bar title's a modifier, wrapping just that part in conditional compilation produces other errors:

```
public struct ExampleView: View {

    private let pageTitle = "Page Title"
    
    public var body: some View {

        VStack(alignment: .center) {
            
            #if os(macOS)
            Text(pageTitle)
                .font(.title)
            #endif

            Spacer()           
            Text("This is the view content")
            Spacer()
        }

        #if !os(macOS)
        .navigationBarTitle(Text(pageTitle))
        #endif
    }
}
```

> Unexpected platform condition (expected 'os', 'arch', or 'swift')
>
> Function declares an opaque return type, but has no return statements in its body from which to infer an underlying type

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I established one approach: Move the main content to another `View` property, then modify it to add the navbar title (if needed) before returning it as `body`. When it's separated this way, conditional compilation can be used.

It's a bit inelegant, but it works. It can also be used to set macOS-specific things, such as the view's overall frame size. Suggestions on a better approach are welcome!

**Swift v5.1**

```
public struct ExampleView: View {

    private let pageTitle = "Page Title"

    #if !os(macOS)
    public var body: some View {
        main.navigationBarTitle(Text(pageTitle))
    }
    #else
    public var body: some View {
        main.frame(
            minWidth: 500,
            minHeight: 500
        )
    }
    #endif
    public var main: some View {

        VStack(alignment: .center) {

            #if os(macOS)
            Text(pageTitle)
                .font(.title)
            #endif

            Spacer()           
            Text("This is the view content")
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you can add an extension to View struct. It will put conditional compilation outside the block and work as you expect

```
#if os(macOS)
extension View {
    func navigationBarTitle(_ title: Text) -> some View {
        return self
    }
}
#endif
```