# Cannot recreate Apple's example with SwiftUI

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I am following this tutorial: https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/building-lists-and-navigation. The only difference with to the original is that I am trying to create a Mac OS app, and not the iOS one.

I have created the following view:

import SwiftUI

```swift
struct LandmarkList: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(landmarkData) { landmark in
                NavigationLink(destination: LandmarkDetail()) {
                    LandmarkRow(landmark: landmark)
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Landmarks"))
        }
    }
}

struct LandmarkList_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        LandmarkList()
    }
}
```

However, I experience the following error (on line `.navigationBarTitle(Text("Landmarks"))`):

```
Value of type 'List<Never, ForEach<[Landmark], Int, HStack<NavigationLink<LandmarkRow, LandmarkDetail>>>>' has no member 'navigationBarTitle'
```

Why is this function not visible? I use the latest macOS Catalina and XCode 11.3.1.

Comment: When compiling for Mac OS, there is no navigationBar it is only avaliable for iOS. Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI Navigation Bar Title in Reusable Cross-Platform (iOS & macOS) View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59359791/swiftui-navigation-bar-title-in-reusable-cross-platform-ios-macos-view)

Comment: Yest, thank you. I wasn't expecting this component not to be universal.